# How to display the user's data with calculations

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to HTML and especially JavaScript and I already have troubles. 
How could I display all the data I took from the user taken through promt.
nothing seems to work from what I know.
here is the code.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var userinput;
        
        var userName = prompt("Please enter your name to proceed");
        if (userName == true)
            {
                document.write ("Welcome to Office Cheapo, "+ userName + ". Here is your invoice:");
            }
        
         var notebook = prompt("How many notebooks do you want to buy?" , "1 to 10");
        if (notebook == true){
            document.write ("Notebooks bought -- "+ notebook);
        }
        
         var pens = prompt("How many pens do you want to buy?", "1 to 10");
        if (pens == true){
            document.write ("Pens bought -- "+ pens);
        }
        
             var usb = prompt("How many USB Flash Drives do you want to buy?", "1 to 10");
        if (usb == true){
           var taxusb = (usb*6.75)*0.05;
        }
        document.write ("USBs bought -- "+ usb);
            
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Cheapo Order</title>        
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Make an order</button>
    
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "display all the data"? Show it in one place?

Comment: yes, so after the user entered all the values they could all show up as
pens bought - 4 
books - 5 and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userName` will either be a string or `null` (if the user canceled the prompt). So `username == true` will always be false and your `document.write` will never be executed.

What you might want is:

```
if (userName) {
```

This will execute your block provided that userName is not a falsy value.

The following are all falsy values:

- null
- undefined
- 0
- ""
- false
- NaN

So as long as the user enters something and presses OK in your prompt, the condition will be met and your code within the if branch, executed.

Comment: yes that worked, actually all worked. But in this case as I understand all the numbers I enter for pens , books and usbs are going to be stings , not integers ?

Comment: You need to convert such numbers from string to integers. You can use ```parseInt()```. For example, ```parseInt(pens)```.